# How to handle Puppeteer "Error: Page crashed!"

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium, digital-ocean, droplet

The scraper I wrote runs perfectly on my PC, A windows OS that runs node.js v14.4.0.

But when I have tried to run it on Digital Ocean Droplet, Ubunto machine, I get for some of the pages the following error: `Page crashed!` with not much information.

Here is the code for printing the error:

```
const handleClose = async (msg) =>{
        console.log(msg)
        page.close();
        browser.close();
        process.exit(1);
}

process.on("uncaughtException", (reason, p) => {
        const a = `Possibly Unhandled Exception at: Promise , ${p}, reason: , ${reason}`
        handleClose(a);
});
```

How do I tackle this one?
And what could cause it? as it works wonderfull on my Windows PC.

Comment: What size droplet? You probably need to go bigger.

Comment: It's the minimal size, 1G RAM + 1vCPU. But wouldn't that be enough for scrapping 1 simple website? I close all pages once done, so there is only 1 page open at a time. And the droplet does only this process.

Answer (score 2):

I have added all memory configurations that I found online and related:

```
const args = [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-infobars',
        '--window-size=1366,768',
        '--unlimited-storage',
        '--full-memory-crash-report',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--force-gpu-mem-available-mb',
        '--disable-gpu'
    ]
```

But that didn't help.

Thanks to pguardiario note, I simply upgrade Droplet from 1G RAM to 2G.
And that did the trick.

I find it strange that to scrape a simple website it takes more than 1G, so I guess Puppeteer takes a lot of resources to run.

**UPDATE**
I had anther page crush, but this time it was related to the server utilazing all the memory. So I removed all this arges from Puppeteer:

```
'--unlimited-storage',
'--full-memory-crash-report',
'--disable-dev-shm-usage',
'--force-gpu-mem-available-mb',
'--disable-gpu'
```

And where left only with the basic ones:

```
const args = [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-infobars',
        '--window-size=1366,768'
]
```

And it's now stable.
So, I guess this needs to be used carefully and removed if not really needed.